Concatenating large file gcloud
I'm trying to concatenate several parquet files into one. My computer lacks enough memory so I decided so use BigQuery and gcloud for this task. However, the whole process seems to be completely mess up...
First I create a bigquery table like this

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.PARQUET,
    write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,  # To append data if the table already exists
)


load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(gcs_uri, dataset_ref.table(table_id), job_config=job_config)
load_job.result()  


My goal then is to export this to gcloud and be able to download a single file. However, first of all bigquery seems to produce chunks that are stored in cloud and these are around 25mg each (hundreds of them). Then, I use gcloud composite function but there is a limit of 32 objects per call. I've seen some workarounds looping over the composite function but they all seem so cumbersome. My question is, isn't just a simpler way to use cloud services to create a single large file and export it locally?

Hi @Luis, As per the google cloud documentation of bigquery export limitations BigQuery can export up to 1 GB of data to a single file. If you are exporting more than 1 GB of data, you must export your data to multiple files.

Thanks for the answer! Yes, that's precisely what I'm trying to circumvent. Is there any alternative that handle it? The big query limitation together with the limit in the gsutil make concatenating a large file a nightmare.

Can you check if this link is helpful?
